# ¿Cómo detener una funcion llamada mediante after al implementar un cronómetro?

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy tratando de hacer un cronómetro en Python y me surgen 2 problemas que no se como resolver.

Lo primero es que al presionar el botón <kbd>Comenzar</kbd> los milisegundos del cronómetro se aceleran, por lo cual falla demasiado.

El otro problema es que no se como detener esa función, ya que parece que al llamarla esta constantemente ejecutándose. Si creo una función y la llamo ejecuta esa función y luego ejecuta la función `Comenzar`.

```
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()
root.title("Cronometro")
root.resizable(0,0)

Minutos=0
Segundos=0
MSegundos=0

Minutos=0
Segundos=0
MSegundos=0

def Comenzar(): 
    global Segundos
    global MSegundos
    global Minutos

    Label.config(text="{:02}:{:02}:{:02}".format(Minutos,Segundos,MSegundos))                   
    Label.after(99,Comenzar)            

    if MSegundos < 100:     
        MSegundos+=10
        Comenzar

    if MSegundos == 100:
        MSegundos=0
        Segundos+=1

    if Segundos == 59 :
        Minutos+=1
        Segundos=0
        MSegundos=0

Frame=tk.Frame(root,width=312,height=300,bg="red")
Frame.pack()

BotonComenzar=tk.Button(Frame,text="Comenzar",font=("Arial",20),width=19,command=Comenzar)
BotonComenzar.place(x=0,y=0)

BotonFinalizar=tk.Button(Frame,text="Finalizar",font=("Arial",20),width=19)
BotonFinalizar.place(x=0,y=245)

Label=tk.Label(font=("Arial",50),text="00:00:00")
Label.place(x=25,y=100)

root.tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Para ejecutar varias funciones al mismo tiempo, investiga Threading. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_multithreading.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La función se ejecuta continuamente porque ella misma programa una nueva ejecución de si misma dentro de 99 milisegundos mediante `Label.after(99,Comenzar)`, mientras no rompas este ciclo la función se ejecutara de nuevo cada 99 milisegundos, aproximadamente, ad infinitum.

Para parar el cronómetro, puedes simplemente usar una variable de control que evite la nueva llamada a `after` desde la propia función si no se cumple la condición.

> `after` no asegura que la función se ejecute exactamente cuando se indica, solo **programa de forma asícrona su ejecución para que ocurra después de un determinado tiempo de espera**. Esto significa, que tu cronómetro seguramente va a ir acumulando pequeños retrasos de milisegundos.

Luego, cada vez que pulses el botón <kbd>Comenzar</kbd> inicias otra nueva secuencia de llamadas a `after`, pero manteniendo las anteriores, por lo que cada 99 milisegundos llamas varias veces a la función y no una, lo que se refleja en esa "aceleración" que comentas. Lo normal es que deshabilites el botón mientras el cronómetro está en funcionamiento, o bien, puedes usarlo para pausarlo.

> **Nota:** la función `comenzar` no es bloqueante en este caso (no tarda mucho en retornar). Si lo fuera, o su ejecución durara mientras el programa esté ejecutándose, habría que recurrir a un hilo o proceso secundario para su ejecución (como comenta @Saelyth). En tal caso, se ha que **comunicar ambos hilos o procesos de forma segura** y **realizar las actualizaciones de la interfaz** (como modificar el texto de un label) **solo desde el hilo principal**.

El código podría quedar así:

```
import tkinter as tk


PRECISION = 10 # Milisegundos entre actualizaciones


def cronometrar():
    global cronometrando
    global tiempo

    if not cronometrando:
        return

    tiempo += PRECISION
    segundos, milisegundos = divmod(tiempo, 1000)
    minutos, segundos = divmod(segundos, 60)

    label.config(text="{:02}:{:02}:{:03}".format(minutos, segundos, milisegundos))
    label.after(PRECISION, cronometrar)


def comenzar():
    global cronometrando

    if cronometrando:
        cronometrando = False
        boton_comenzar.config(text="Reanudar")
    else:
        cronometrando = True
        boton_comenzar.config(text="Pausar")
        cronometrar()


def finalizar():
    global cronometrando
    global tiempo

    cronometrando = False
    tiempo = 0
    boton_comenzar.config(text="Comenzar")
    label.config(text="00:00:000")


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Cronómetro")
root.resizable(0, 0)

cronometrando = False
tiempo = 0

frame = tk.Frame(root, width=312, height=300, bg="red")
frame.pack()

boton_comenzar = tk.Button(frame,
                           text="Comenzar",
                           font=("Arial", 20),
                           width=19,
                           command=comenzar
                           )
boton_comenzar.place(x=0, y=0)

boton_finalizar = tk.Button(frame,
                            text="Finalizar",
                            font=("Arial", 20),
                            width=19,
                            command=finalizar
                            )
boton_finalizar.place(x=0, y=245)

label = tk.Label(frame, font=("Arial", 50), text="00:00:00")
label.place(x=25, y=100)

root.mainloop()
```

Si nos preocupa la precisión y la posibilidad de ir acumulando errores, una opción más precisa es usar `time.perf_counter` (Python >= 3.3) por ejemplo.

```
import time
import tkinter as tk


class Cronometro(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, *args, precision=10, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(root, *args, **kwargs)

        self.precision = precision
        self._timer = None
        self._pausado = True
        self._time = 0

        self.boton_cronometrar = tk.Button(self,
                                           text="Comenzar",
                                           font=("Arial", 20),
                                           width=19,
                                           command=self.cronometrar
                                           )
        self.boton_resetear = tk.Button(self,
                                        text="Resetear",
                                        font=("Arial", 20),
                                        width=19,
                                        command=self.resetear
                                        )
        self.label = tk.Label(self, font=("Arial", 50), text="00:00:000")

        self.boton_cronometrar.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, minsize=50)
        self.label.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(3, minsize=50)
        self.boton_resetear.grid(row=4, column=0)


    def cronometrar(self):
        if self._pausado:
            self._pausado = False
            self.boton_cronometrar.config(text="Pausar")
            self._timer = time.perf_counter()
            self._run()
        else:
            self._pausado = True
            self.boton_cronometrar.config(text="Reanudar")

    def resetear(self):
        self._pausado = True
        self._set_time(0)
        self.boton_cronometrar.config(text="Iniciar")

    def _run(self):
        if self._pausado:
            return
        last_timer = self._timer
        self._timer = time.perf_counter()
        self._set_time(self._time + (self._timer - last_timer))
        self.after(self.precision, self._run)

    def _set_time(self, t):
        self._time = t
        segundos = int(t)
        milisegundos = int((t - segundos) * 1000)
        minutos, segundos = divmod(segundos, 60)
        self.label.config(text=f"{minutos:02}:{segundos:02}:{milisegundos:03}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Cronómetro")
    root.resizable(False, False)
    cronometro = Cronometro(root, width=500, height=300, bg="red")
    cronometro.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]